# ESlint : Component should be written as a pure function error when I'm creating a class component using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am writing a react class component in my react-native project. I am using ESLint in my project extending the airbnb syling rules.

This component has a form which stores it's form values in Redux. It initialises the form values from Redux and updates them using an action creator (called employeeUpdate) which is imported into the file. I don't need any lifecycle methods or a constructor in my component in this case.

The problem is that ESLint complains that I should be writing this component as a pure function. I can't write it as a pure function since it is consuming state from Redux as props. This is the specific error :

[eslint] Component should be written as a pure function

Here is my code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Picker, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';
import { employeeUpdate } from '../actions';

const styles = {
  pickerTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20
  }
};

class EmployeeCreate extends Component {
  render() {
    const { name, phone, shift, employeeUpdate } = this.props;

    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Name"
            placeholder="Jane"
            value={name}
            onChangeText={value => employeeUpdate({ prop: 'name', value })}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Phone"
            placeholder="555-555-5555"
            value={phone}
            onChangeText={value => employeeUpdate({ prop: 'phone', value })}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
          <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Shift</Text>
          <Picker
            selectedValue={shift}
            onValueChange={value => employeeUpdate({ prop: 'shift', value })}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
          >
            <Picker.Item label="Monday" value="Monday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Tuesday" value="Tuesday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Wednesday" value="Wednesday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Thursday" value="Thursday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Friday" value="Friday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Saturday" value="Saturday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Sunday" value="Sunday" />
          </Picker>
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Button>Create</Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { name, phone, shift } = state.employeeForm;
  return { name, phone, shift };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { employeeUpdate }
)(EmployeeCreate);
```

I gave it a shot and tried writing it as a pure function (code below), but when I destructured the action creator, ESLint again complained that my action creator has already been declared (since it was imported at the top of the file)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Picker, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';
import { employeeUpdate } from '../actions';

const styles = {
  pickerTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20
  }
};

const EmployeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift, employeeUpdate }) => (
  <Card>
    <CardSection>
      <Input
        label="Name"
        placeholder="Jane"
        value={name}
        onChangeText={value => employeeUpdate({ prop: 'name', value })}
      />
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection>
      <Input
        label="Phone"
        placeholder="555-555-5555"
        value={phone}
        onChangeText={value => employeeUpdate({ prop: 'phone', value })}
      />
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Shift</Text>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={shift}
        onValueChange={value => employeeUpdate({ prop: 'shift', value })}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <Picker.Item label="Monday" value="Monday" />
        <Picker.Item label="Tuesday" value="Tuesday" />
        <Picker.Item label="Wednesday" value="Wednesday" />
        <Picker.Item label="Thursday" value="Thursday" />
        <Picker.Item label="Friday" value="Friday" />
        <Picker.Item label="Saturday" value="Saturday" />
        <Picker.Item label="Sunday" value="Sunday" />
      </Picker>
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection>
      <Button>Create</Button>
    </CardSection>
  </Card>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { name, phone, shift } = state.employeeForm;
  return { name, phone, shift };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { employeeUpdate }
)(EmployeeCreate);
```

Is there a way around this issue? Can I not write it as a React class component, not use any lifecyle methods and not get any errors from ESLint?

**Note** :

1. I know I can disable the rule, but I want to be warned by ESLint in other components of my project.
2. Maybe the action creator can be imported under some other alias but then I still don't think that's the best way to write my components.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need state nor lifecycle methods, pure function is the way to go.

I see 2 ways to fix your code:

1. Use a different file for the connect. It's cool to separate in one file the jsx with your pure component, and use another one to connect the props and action creators.
2. If you prefer to have everything in the same file, you can always rename your prop like:

   const EmployeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift, employeeUpdate: updateEmployee }) => (

Now your employeeUpdate is declared as updateEmployee inside the component, and there's no duplicate declaration.

PS: Actually, with Hooks, pure functions may be always the way to go.